# After migrating from SDK 28 to SDK 29 in Android my app crashed and facing : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), error in Android studio 3.4.1

Tags: android, memory-management, android-ndk, android-10.0, android-native-library

Iam facing the issue only in OnePlus, Samsung , Poco F1 with Android OS version 10.

It's working in pixel devices with Android 10.

Please find the error logs below

---

```
Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/beryllium/beryllium:10/QKQ1.190828.002/V11.0.6.0.QEJMIXM:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2020-03-16 18:10:34+0530
pid: 2594, tid: 2737, name: JavaBridge  >>> com.mymobile<<<
uid: 10362
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x7188e089db
Cause: execute-only (no-read) memory access error; likely due to data in .text.
    x0  0000000000000100  x1  000000705d3f2fb0  x2  0000000000000000  x3  0000000000000008
    x4  00000000000000e2  x5  000000705d3fbd60  x6  000000705d3fbd60  x7  707265676e69662e
    x8  0000007188e089d4  x9  0000000000000000  x10 0000000000000007  x11 0000000000000000
    x12 0000000000000000  x13 0000000000000001  x14 000000705d3f2f58  x15 000000705d3f4bcc
    x16 00000060a530d558  x17 0000007188e0ae20  x18 000000001ba3a243  x19 000000705d3f7038
    x20 0000000000000001  x21 000000705d3f4188  x22 000000705d3f6f1c  x23 0000000000000002
    x24 0000000000000002  x25 0000007081ea45b0  x26 000000710786b8b0  x27 0000000000000005
    x28 0000000000000001  x29 000000705d3f6f90
    sp  000000705d3f31e0  lr  000000708c9058d8  pc  000000708c9063d8

backtrace:
      #00 pc 00000000000053d8  /data/app/com.mymobile-_0ls0Aom7N8BP86o4bZVYQ==/lib/arm64/libag3.so (BuildId: 25ee893fb2620c6009ca1a6ef581e24e27c00a36)
      #01 pc 000000000000c2c4  /data/app/com.mymobile-_0ls0Aom7N8BP86o4bZVYQ==/lib/arm64/libag3.so (BuildId: 25ee893fb2620c6009ca1a6ef581e24e27c00a36)
      #02 pc 000000000002b0d4  /data/app/com.mymobile-_0ls0Aom7N8BP86o4bZVYQ==/lib/arm64/libag3.so (Java_com_apiguard3_signals_NdkManager_collectSignal+196) (BuildId: 25ee893fb2620c6009ca1a6ef581e24e27c00a36)
      #03 pc 00000000000b90fc  /data/app/com.mymobile-_0ls0Aom7N8BP86o4bZVYQ==/oat/arm64/base.odex (art_jni_trampoline+236)
      #04 pc 0000000000136334  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
      #05 pc 0000000000144fec  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+244) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
      #06 pc 00000000002e27cc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+384) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
      #07 pc 00000000002dda2c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+892) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
      #08 pc 00000000005a20b0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+424) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
      #09 pc 0000000000130914  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
      #10 pc 0000000000de4afa  /data/app/com.mymobile-_0ls0Aom7N8BP86o4bZVYQ==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.apiguard3.signals.NdkManager.b0414ДДДД0414+20)
      #11 pc 00000000002b3ae0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEbb.llvm.17460956533834400288+240) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
      #12 pc 00000000005912f0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1032) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
      #13 pc 000000000013f468  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
      #14 pc 0000000000136334  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 2bc2e11d57f839316bf2a42bbfdf943a)
      #15 pc 0000000000144fec  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JVal
```

Can any one help in resolving this 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find any fix ?

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of this crash is caused by behavior change from Android 10.
Please refer to the following pages to understand the problem:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all

In a summary the issue is:
Starting in Android 10, executable segments of system binaries and libraries are mapped into memory execute-only (non-readable) as a hardening technique against code-reuse attacks. If your app performs read operations into memory segments marked as execute-only – whether from bug, vulnerability, or intentional memory inspection – the system sends a SIGSEGV signal to your app.

As workaround it says to call "mprotect" to execute the method where crash happen.
You can refer here to understand how to call this method:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html

I would say it is very annoying to implement this workaround as it add additional system call and not convenient at all.However i don't see a better way.

Comment: how can i add mprotect() method. do i need to convert exiting project to ndk project. can you provide steps.