# Android app closing on start. giving error 'Cause: execute-only (no-read) memory access error; likely due to data in .text'

Tags: android

MY app closing in startup and throwing error.

```
Cause: execute-only (no-read) memory access error; likely due to data in .text.
```

This is described in Android 10 behaviour changes
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all#xom-binaries

But i'm not able proceed with this solution. how can use `mProtect()` method.

my project is not ndk. my libraries, that are using native code

the bellow link also seen but i'm not able to do how can i solve

[After migrating from SDK 28 to SDK 29 in Android my app crashed and facing : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), error in Android studio 3.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60720511/after-migrating-from-sdk-28-to-sdk-29-in-android-my-app-crashed-and-facing-sig)

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/execute-only-memory

this issue came when i'm used my android sdk is 30. but when i use sdk to 28 issue not coming

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/android-ndk/6xTuTkguftY, https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/execute-only-memory#disabling may help you